# Unable to generate ROC curves for multiclassification models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been working to generate ROC curves for these models, but keep getting this error message;

> UndefinedMetricWarning: No positive samples in y_true, true positive value should be meaningless
> warnings.warn("No positive samples in y_true, "

This is a snippet of my code:

```
def roc_curves(self): 

    ms = {}

    y = label_binarize(self.train.iloc[:, 0], classes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    n_classes = y.shape[1]

    ms['ada'] = OneVsRestClassifier(AdaBoostClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=self.seed, criterion='gini', max_features='log2', max_depth=4), algorithm='SAMME'))
    ms['ada'].fit(self.train.iloc[:, 1:], y)
    ms['rf'] = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=self.seed, criterion='gini', class_weight='balanced', max_features='auto', n_estimators=10))
    ms['rf'].fit(self.train.iloc[:, 1:], y)
    ms['svm'] = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(random_state=self.seed, C=0.1, gamma=1, kernel='poly'))
    ms['svm'].fit(self.train.iloc[:, 1:], y)
    ms['nb'] = OneVsRestClassifier(GaussianNB(var_smoothing=0.08111308307896872))
    ms['nb'].fit(self.train.iloc[:, 1:], y)
    ms['knn'] = OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', metric='minkowski', n_neighbors=4, weights='distance'))
    ms['knn'].fit(self.train.iloc[:, 1:], y)

    yy = label_binarize(self.test.iloc[:, 0], classes=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr, tpr, roc = [], [], []
        for k, m in ms.items():
            predict = m.predict(self.test.iloc[:, 1:])
            _ = roc_curve(yy[:, i], predict[:, i])
```

Comment: As the warning clearly says, there are no positive samples in `y_true`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your `yy` variable has all values of the same class.